# ATG & Flex via AMF?

Tags: apache-flex, amf, atg

How easy might it be to build a front end with flex, and have ATG as the backend and do all communication / integration via AMF, using BlazeDS or Live Cycle Data Services?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple in the coming ATG version 10. There were several demos of Flash based and Swing based clients done by ATG using the not-yet-released ATG 10.

If you are working on some home-grown solution, with arrival of v 10 it my become obsolete. 
See also https://community.atg.com/docs/DOC-1638 - Flex based catalog browsing demo.